# What is the Clojure equivalent of a "public static final" constant in Java

Tags: java, performance, optimization, clojure, constants

I'm writing some Clojure code that depends upon a number of constants.

They will be used within tight inner loops, so it's important that they will be used and optimised as efficiently as possible by the Clojure compiler+JVM combination. I would normally used a "public static final" constant in Java for the same purpose.

What is the best way to declare these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `def`-ing things in the global namespace is about as close as you can come.

Comment: Adding the :const metadata will cause it to be inlined at compile time, see answer by @amalloy.  The global defs are vars, which while close, can be tweaked and get resolved at run time.

Answer (score 6):

I believe Clojure 1.3 (or maybe 1.4) allows you to put a `^:constant` tag on a `def`, signifying to the compiler that this should be a constant and all references should be resolved at compile-time.

## Edit

Apparently it's Clojure 1.3, and it's `^:const`, not `^:constant`. See [How does Clojure ^:const work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162558/how-does-clojure-const-work) for a summary.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `defconst`, so just using a global def is idiomatic; as far as optimisation is concerned, the JIT will make things fast.

Answer (score 3):

If really, really, really want the constant in place (I believe, the JIT will notice the value being constant and do the right thing, though), you can use a macro.

```
(defmacro my-constant [] 5)
```

This is rather ugly, but performance critical code will always be ugly, I guess.

```
(do-stuff (my-constant) in-place)
```

Pay care what you put into the macro, though! I wouldn't this for more than some literal constants. In particular not objects.

Answer (score 3):

If just using `def` is not fast enough, you could try creating a `let` bound alias before entering your tight loop to avoid going through a var each time.

Comment: Thanks - so am I correct in saying that if you don't do this, then it will end up dereferencing the var every time the constant is accessed?

Answer (score 2):

as said above use def or atom, remember, data is immutable, so if you declare some constants in a list, they don't change.

Comment: If he wanted something mutable he would ask for a constant and anyway you woulnd normaly make a list with atoms. You would make a atom list or a ref list.