# mark a function returned by builtin hight-level fn as const failed

Tags: clojure

I defined a function that shouldn't be changed, so I was thinking I could use const meta to restrict that. It works good until I use builtin high-level function that generate another function

```
snitch.core=> (defn gen-foo [] (fn [_] true))
#'snitch.core/gen-foo
snitch.core=> (def ^:const foo (gen-foo))
#'snitch.core/foo
snitch.core=> (foo 1)
true

snitch.core=> (def ^:const foo (every-pred even?))
#'snitch.core/foo
snitch.core=> (foo 1)
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class clojure.core$every_pred$ep1__6420  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:163)

snitch.core=> (def ^:const foo (constantly 3))
#'snitch.core/foo
snitch.core=> (foo)
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class clojure.core$constantly$fn__4085  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:163)
```

I'm confused by the error msg.

Also why function I defined could being used, but function generated by builtin function couldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of `:const` metadata. In Clojure all variables are persistent and can not be changed.

`:const` metadata in Clojure works pretty much like `inline` directive in `C++`, telling Clojure to replace variable with its value during compilation, instead of dereferencing it on runtime.

Please, see [How does Clojure ^:const work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9162558/1202461)

Comment: then I also could mark regex pattern as const, right?