# Meaning of ^{:const true}

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to learn [Langohr](http://clojurerabbitmq.info/articles/getting_started.html) and I came across this piece of code:

```
(def ^{:const true} default-exchange-name "")
```

What does it do?

I'm not sure if its a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162558). My question is regarding a map while ^:const is just a keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Clojure ^:const work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162558/how-does-clojure-const-work)

Comment: @NathanHughes I'm not sure. My question is a map while ^:const is just a keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the two notations [according to the docs](http://clojure.org/reference/metadata).

> ^:dynamic obj - Sets the given keyword to true in the object’s
>   metadata. Equivalent to ^{:dynamic true} obj