# Why can I change immutable variables in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, binding

I come from the Javascript world where const is used to declare immutable variables.

The definition of a immutable variable is explained in the same way in Clojure.

However, this is allowed:

```
(def cheese "I like cheese")

...
...

(def cheese "Actually, I changed my mind)
```

When I run this, the repl gives me `actually, I changed my mind`.

In JS, it will throw an error because a `const` cannot be changed.

I would appreciate it if someone explained where my understanding of `immutable variables` is incorrect in the clojure world?

Thanks

Comment: When you rebind the name it points to a different variable, not a modified version of the old one. You didn't _change_ the variable; instead, you _replaced_ it.

Comment: Ahhh okay so the variables in JS which behave like this are defined by `let`, which allow us to replace the value but not change the current value. Clojure is like this for standard. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Because Clojure prioritizes practicality over purity it offers ways to avoid that standard behavior, but that's the default out of the box with things that aren't explicitly documented and intended to behave otherwise.

Comment: BTW, if memory serves there's metadata you can add to a `def` to tell it not to allow rebinding. Maybe `^:const`, but that's admittedly a top-of-the-head guess.

Comment: I was a little imprecise in my language above, btw. Instead of saying you're creating a new variable I should have said you're rebinding the existing var (that being the reference type `def` creates) to point to a new and distinct value instead of modifying the old string in place (which isn't even possible in the underlying JVM implementation, strings being immutable there)

Comment: Yup, const was right; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162558/how-does-clojure-const-work

Comment: Ahh okay. I apologies for the references to JS but its the only programming lang, I know. 

Normal variables in clojure = let in JS
Contants in clojure with ^:const = const in JS

Comment: BTW, it's usually considered bad form in clojure to rebind vars as part of general program operation -- if you're designing something expecting to want to attach a new value on a regular basis, it's probably appropriate to use a different reference type, like an atom (or, if you need STM features, a ref). The ability to rebind vars is more of a tool for letting folks refine their software via a REPL (or update it online via a nrepl or such) than a first-class proper way to update values associated with a name on a regular basis.

Comment: I see. Sometimes in larger programs in the JS world, I would accidently reuse a variable name. Const will help remind me that its already used. BTW - i tried ^:const but I can still rebind the value later on in the program. Anythoughts?

Comment: const changes how things are compiled to directly inline references without doing a runtime lookup through the var. If you're not doing AOT compilation it's not nearly so relevant.

Comment: Anyhow -- the convention for good-smelling clojure is that you only use `def` in a top-level namespace, never in a function. If you follow that rule, it's hard to set things more than once by accident.

Comment: ...btw, did you read the answer to the other question I linked? It does describe the limitations on `^:const`.

Comment: You might also think about using [`defonce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defonce)

Comment: Def in top level namespace and I am assuming `let` within the functions? Apologies, I missed that link. Thanks.

Comment: Typically `let` in a function wherever you can; when you can't use `let`, then it's contextually dependent. For example, if you need a function to modify/maintain a globally-visible value (which can be a little bit of a smell, but is often appropriate when used sparingly), then maybe you do a top-level `(def something (atom nil))` in its namespace before the function is defined and then inside that function use `reset!` or `swap!` as appropriate to update the value held inside that atom.

Comment: This is insanely valuable. Thank you Charles. You are a true gentleman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise, Clojure has ***immutable values***, not ***immutable variables***.  After all, the name `Var` is shorthand for "variable".

Imagine the number `5`. You never need to worry about who "owns" it, or that someone might change its definition. Also, there can be many copies of that number used for many purposes in many parts of your program. Clojure extends this idea to collection values such as the vector `[1 2 3]` or the map `{:first "Joe" :last "Cool"}`.

Having said that, in Clojure a `Var` is normally used for a global "constant" value that is never changed (although it could). Using a Clojure `Atom` (global or local) is normal for values that do change. There are many other options (functions like `reduce` have an internal accumulator, for example).

This [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) is a good place to start, esp the books "Getting Clojure" and "Brave Clojure".

Comment: I have much to learn. I am curious though, what do you mean by `the var`?

Comment: if you'd like an example of changing the value of a number, python3 offers this gem:      >>> import ctypes
     >>> ctypes.c_int.from_address(id(42) + 24).value = 1
     >>> 1+42
     2

Answer (score 2):

As Alan mentions, Clojure has immutable values, not immutable variables.

When you execute

```clj
(def x 42)
```

what happens is that a Clojure `Var` is created, the Var is bound to the name (aka symbol) `x`, and the immutable value `42` is placed inside the Var.  A Var is a container of values.  Typically, only one value is ever placed in a Var.  But, as in your example, there can be different immutable values placed inside the Var at different times.

Reading [Clojure Vars and the Global Environment](https://clojure.org/reference/vars) might be helpful.